# Android Compose LazyColumn View Interference

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Multiple posts appear

```kotlin
LazyColumn(
    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
) {
    items(postData) {
        Column {
           Post(postData = it)
        }
    }
}
```

When I click the checkbox of one among several Post views, the checkboxes of other views are also clicked, How can I have different states?

```kotlin
@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
@Composable
fun Post(
    postData: PostData, viewModel: PostViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {
    val postGoodCounts = rememberSaveable { mutableLongStateOf(postData.goodCounts) }
    val goodStatus = rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(postData.goodStatus ?: false) }
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 10.dp)
        ) {
            Row(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .height(30.dp)
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .padding(bottom = 10.dp)
            ) {
                CustomCheckbox(
                    checked = goodStatus.value,
                    onPainter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_good_true),
                    offPainter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_good_false),
                ) {
                    //check event
                }
            }
            Text(
                text = "good $postGoodCounts",
                modifier = Modifier.padding(bottom = 10.dp),
                style = Title5
            )
        }
}
```

Comment: The code you provided looks good and works as intended when I replace `CustomCheckbox` by a regular `Checkbox` with `onCheckedChange = { goodStatus.value = !goodStatus.value }`.

Comment: Even if you change it to Checkbox, it interferes with other views (when you click a checkbox, all other checkboxes are also clicked).

Comment: Not for me, though, not with this code: `Checkbox(
    checked = goodStatus.value,
    onCheckedChange = { goodStatus.value = !goodStatus.value },
)`